# GraphQL error: Internal server error when accessing graphQL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using GraphQL with `wpgraphql` inside a WP setup. I have been using the service without any problems until I updated a Custom Post Type and it stopped working.

`message: "Internal server error", category: "internal",`

But what is odd is that it still returns the data, along with the error.

Doing the same query in graphiQL works without any flaws. Looking at the request, the only difference is no cookies are sent with the failing request.

I have enabled: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` but no new errors are displayed.

The query is rather simple:

```
{
  rankings {
    edges {
      node {
        rankingId
        id
        commentStatus
        content
        date
        title
        uri
        link
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `define( 'GRAPHQL_DEBUG', true );` to get the full error message from **WPGraphQL**

Comment: One should add the above line in the file called `wp-config.php` located `/Users/<YourUserName>/Local Sites/<YourWordPressProject>/app/public/wp-config.php`, in case it wasn't clear. :)